# Django: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to effectively make a Reddit clone just for practice with Django and I am trying to set up my upvote/downvote system with just a simple integer(upvote adds one, downvotes subtract one) however when I hit my "upvote" or "downvote" buttons it gives me the error `'str' object has no attribute 'get'`. I have no idea what is causing this and all of the other answers with this error were not at all related, any help would be awesome.
Full TraceBack:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 116, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
  File "C:\Users\Andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\clickjacking.py", line 26, in process_response
    if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

My Model:

```py
class post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ranking = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

My Views:

```py
class Feed(ListView):
    model = post
    template_name = 'thefeed/feed.html'

def UpvoteView(request, pk):
    selected_post = post.objects.get(pk=pk)
    selected_post.ranking+=1
    selected_post.save()
    return reverse('feed-home')

def DownvoteView(request, pk):
    selected_post = post.objects.get(pk=pk)
    selected_post.ranking-=1
    selected_post.save()
    return reverse('feed-home')
```

My Urls:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.Feed.as_view(), name="feed-home"),
    path('post/<int:pk>/downvote', views.DownvoteView, name='downvote-post'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/upvote', views.DownvoteView, name='upvote-post'),
]
```

My Feed.html(homepage):

```html
{% block content %}
<div class="announcement">
    <h5 style="background: yellow;">Forum.Chat is the Internet's home for debate on any topic, keep it civil!</h5>
</div>
<br>
{% for post in object_list %}
    <div style="margin-bottom: 2%;">
        <h3><a href="{% url 'feed-post' post.pk %}">{{post.title}}</a><a href="#"></h3>
        <p><a href="#">By: {{post.author}}</a><a href="{% url 'edit-post' post.pk %}">    Edit Post</a></p>
        <p><a href="{% url 'upvote-post' pk=post.pk %}">Upvote</a><a href="{% url 'downvote-post' pk=post.pk %}">    DownVote</a></p>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Please [edit] and add the _full_ error traceback to your question.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I will update it.

Comment: `return reverse('feed-home')` why are you returning a url? You are supposed to return some _response_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your views you write `return reverse('feed-home')` but this will return a **string** being the url of the url pattern named `feed-home`. A view should *always* be returning a response object. As a shortcut you can use the [`redirect` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) to return a response which will redirect the user:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect


def UpvoteView(request, pk):
    selected_post = post.objects.get(pk=pk)
    selected_post.ranking+=1
    selected_post.save()
    return redirect('feed-home')  # Change here

def DownvoteView(request, pk):
    selected_post = post.objects.get(pk=pk)
    selected_post.ranking-=1
    selected_post.save()
    return redirect('feed-home')  # Change here
```

---

> **Note**: Class names should ideally be in `PascalCase` not `snake_case` also function / variable names should be in `snake_case`
> not `PascalCase`. Hence instead of <s>`post`</s> your model should be
> named **`Post`** and instead of <s>`UpvoteView`</s> it should be
> **`upvote_view`**, etc. Have a look at [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for
> Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: Thanks for the note re different cases, I will update them. Changing it to redirect worked however now even if I click on upvote it still decreases the score. Any ideas why this would be happening?

Comment: @Agarb ah that is because you set the view for both the url patterns as `views.DownvoteView`, you want to be setting the view for `'post/<int:pk>/upvote'` as `views.UpvoteView`

Answer (score 1):

could you try it like this:

```
def UpvoteView(request, pk):
    selected_post = post.objects.get(pk=pk)
    selected_post.ranking = selected_post.ranking +1
    selected_post.save()
    return reverse('feed-home')
```

are you able to get  post.objects.all()

Comment: Tried it and I am getting the same error, I am able to get post.objects.all()

Comment: are you using custom manager for the model ?
in the error log please note the line number of the code.

 selected_post = post.objects.get(pk=pk)   - is this the line causing the error.